# How do I use "while" in this situation?

Tags: python

I am currently making a 'Guess the Animal' game, where the user will input a question it will generate an answer. However, I am stuck on trying to make a 'This question isn't recognised' while loop.

```
while questionone.find("bird") or questionone.find("mammal") not in questionone:
    print("This question isn't recognised.")
    print("Ask another question or check for typos.")
    print("This will not count towards your 5 questions.")
    questionone = input("What is your question? ")
    questionone = questionone.lower()
```

How do I fix this?
Any replies would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The loop condition would be

```
while 'bird' not in questionone and 'mammal' not in questionone:
```

To extend this to a set of words you want to check against, you could use

```
while not any(word in questionone for word in {'bird', 'mammal', 'etc'}:
```